# azure Function proxy is not working on Linux systems

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I created an azure functions premium tier to be able to have proxies on it but when trying to add a proxy I cant[This is what im getting right now !!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uMkk.png)

Comment: You need to edit the proxy.json on local first, then deploy function to azure. I think azure function  based on linux system can not edit on azure.

Comment: Hello, when you get a textual error please write it in the question so it becomes searchable for the next person looking for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `Bowman` mentioned in the comments, `Azure function` based on `Linux` systems cannot edit `proxy` on the `Azure portal`.

You need to create a `proxies.json` locally and deploy it to the `Azure portal`. the `proxies.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/proxies",
    "proxies": {
        "proxy1": {
            "matchCondition": {
                "methods": [ "GET" ],
                "route": "/api/{test}"
            },
            "backendUri": "https://<AnotherApp>.azurewebsites.net/api/<FunctionName>"
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:**

`proxies.json` is located in the root of a function app directory. For more details, you can refer to this [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-proxies#advanced-configuration).